# Разбить строку на слова с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как разбить предложение на слова с помощью
Python?

Answer (score 7):

```
string = 'wbetwte wetb wt bwt b wte'
print(string.split())
```

Comment: ValueError: empty separator

Comment: @D.Violet всё работает https://repl.it/repls/JointMammothAdvance

Comment: ошибка, которую я указал, при использовании Python 3.7

Comment: @D.Violet все прекрасно работает на Python 3.7: https://i.stack.imgur.com/03YPg.png

Comment: да, я перепроверил. моя невнимательность...

Answer (score 2):

```
a = 'Как разбить предложение на слова с помощью Python?'

print(a.split(' '))
>>> ['Как', 'разбить', 'предложение', 'на', 'слова', 'с', 'помощью', 'Python?']

print(a.split(' ')[7])
>>> Python?
```

Comment: есть разбивать по пробелам  можно не указывать `a.split(' ')`  а просто написать  `a.split()`